# Returning HTML page after success login with ResponseEntity method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this controller that allow user to log in to my site.

```
@PostMapping("/login")
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<?> login(@Valid @ModelAttribute("login") LoginDTO dto, Model model) {
Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(dto.getUsername(), dto.getPassword()));
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();

RefreshToken refreshToken = new RefreshToken();
refreshToken.setOwner(user);
refreshTokenRepository.save(refreshToken);

model.addAttribute("login", dto);

String accessToken = jwtHelper.generateAccessToken(user);
String refreshTokenString = jwtHelper.generateRefreshToken(user, refreshToken);

return ResponseEntity.ok(new TokenDTO(user.getId(), accessToken, refreshTokenString));

}
```

I'm trying to create a redirect, so after user is logged in successfully redirect him to index page.

As you can see I have this as return `return ResponseEntity.ok(new TokenDTO(user.getId(), accessToken, refreshTokenString));`

When I change that to this:

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Location", "/api/auth/index");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, HttpStatus.FOUND);
```

User is successfully redirected to right API but I still got in console
`d.t.s.security.AccessTokenEntryPoint:unauthorized`

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full 
authentication is required to access this resource
```

But when I set return to this

```
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new TokenDTO(user.getId(), accessToken, 
    refreshTokenString));
```

After user enter right credentials everything is fine and I dont have in console bad credentials or something so everything works fine, except that part about redirecting which I cant make

Comment: Using location header browser triggers a new request to the provided url. So you'll need to pass the token (e.g. as cookie) to the client to be used for the next request

Comment: Understand, but how I can achieve that

Comment: When I test this in postman there is no a single error on any API, but when I try to login or register from html in browser there is always error `Full authentication is required to access this resource` or `unauthorized`, so I guess there is a problem in configuration for security with HTML and access page, but I have this in `WebSecurityConfig`: `.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()` and its still showing same errors when I try to access resource via browser

Comment: I mean when I hit a `http://localhost:8080/api/auth/loginForm` immediately in stack trace appear `d.t.s.security.AccessTokenEntryPoint     : unauthorized` and `Full authentication is required to access this resource`, but when I access this in postman its all good, no errors in postman no errors in IDE stack trace

Comment: try this... https://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward

Comment: Hi, I totally random found a solution (I still don't know if it's the best but so far it works.) In WebSecurityConfig I edited this line like this `.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll().and().formLogin();` - I added `.formLogin();` and now its all good

Answer (score 0):

add **.httpBasic();** at last in your configuration file and chek it